# PythonBridge: how to correctly set up current working directory of the child process?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, linux, npm

I have a Node.js project which must be integrated with a previously written Python script. Currently Node.js project is deployed in such a way that the Python script must be placed inside of the Node root directory. Under these conditions the whole project runs well and there are no error warnings. For some reasons, I would like to put the Python script outside of the Node root directory. Thus, I have added .cwd parameter:

```
const python = pythonBridge({
python: 'python3',
stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
cwd: '/dir1/dir2/'                      # added line
})
```

Now when the Python script is inside of /dir1/dir2/ folder, an error message is generated:

```
ERROR: (node:14870) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: logger is not defined
at /NodeJSrootFolder/dist/NodeJSFactory.js:69:7
```

Being a newcomer in Node.js, I would like to know besides .cwd which parameters must be changed in order to make project run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions posted here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-bridge), current working directory of the child process must be specified via .cwd option:

```
var python = pythonBridge(options)
options.cwd - String Current working directory of the child process
```

As I have mentioned in my question, this solution doesn't work. Actually, .js file ignore .cwd option and looks for the Python script inside of the Node.js root directory. In order to resolve the problem, the full address must be specified inside of the FS object:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
// ...
// somewhere below
// ...
let reads = [
fs.readFile('/dir1/dir2/myPythonScript.py'),] // vs. fs.readFile('./myPythonScript.py')
```

I am not sure whether it is a normal procedure or some dirty hack, but it works for my project.